# If $|z+2|-|z-2|=2$ and $\dfrac{z-a}{z+a}=ik$, where $k$ is a real parameter, $a\in \mathbb R$ has exactly two solution. Then interval of $a$ is?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> > If $|z+2|-|z-2|=2$ and $\dfrac{z-a}{z+a}=ik$, where $k$ is a real parameter, $a\in \mathbb R$ has exactly two solution. Then interval of $a$ is?

**My Approach:**

First Curve is one branch of a hyperbola with its transverse axis of length $2$ and conjugate axis with length of $2\sqrt3$.

So hyperbola is $\dfrac{x^2}{1}-\dfrac{y^2}{3}=1$.

And second curve is circle $(k^2-1)x^2+(k^2-1)y^2+2a(k^2+1)x+(k^2-1)a^2=0$ with center $\bigg(\dfrac{-a(k^2+1)}{k^2-1},0\bigg)$  and radius $\bigg|\dfrac{2ak}{k^2-1}\bigg|$.

Then I put $y^2=3(x^2-1)$ obtained from hyperbola into circle $(k^2-1)x^2+(k^2-1)y^2+2a(k^2+1)x+(k^2-1)a^2=0$

Then I obtained the equation $4(k^2-1)x^2+2a(k^2+1)x+(k^2-1)(a^2-3)$

**Now I don't Know how to proceed further?**

**Second Doubt**

What if there was two branches of hyperbola for example $\bigg ||z+2|-|z-2|\bigg |=2$?

Comment: The second curve is a circle centred at $(0,0)$ and with radius $|a|$. Hence $a^2>1$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca How exactly?

Comment: Just make a sketch of that hyperbola branch and that circle, and you'll see.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I did but I am not getting any conclusion. I mean why center must be $(0,0)$

Comment: Your second equation $z-a=ik(z+a)$ means that the line joining $z$ with $a$ is perpendicular to the line joining $z$ with $-a$. Hence the triangle having $z$, $a$ and $-a$ as vertices has a right angle at $z$. That means $z$ lies on the circle having $a$ and $-a$ as endpoints of a diameter .

Comment: By the way, how did you get your (wrong) equation for the circle?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not hard to show that:

$$\frac{\text{z}-\text{a}}{\text{z}+\text{a}}=i\text{k}\space\Longrightarrow\space\begin{cases}
\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)-\text{a}^2=0\\
\\
\text{k}=\frac{2\text{a}\Im\left(\text{z}\right)}{\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)+\text{a}\right)^2}
\end{cases}\tag1$$

We also see that:

$$\left|\text{z}+2\right|-\left|\text{z}-2\right|=2\space\Longrightarrow\space\sqrt{\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)+2\right)^2+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}-\sqrt{\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-2\right)^2+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}=2\tag2$$

Now, we can solve the following equation:

$$\sqrt{\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)+2\right)^2+\text{a}^2-\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)}-\sqrt{\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-2\right)^2+\text{a}^2-\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)}=2\space\Longrightarrow\space$$
$$\Re\left(\text{z}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3+\text{a}^2}}{2}\tag3$$

And:

$$\frac{3+\text{a}^2}{4}+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)-\text{a}^2=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\Im\left(\text{z}\right)=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3\left(\text{a}^2-1\right)}}{2}\tag4$$

And we can also see that:

$$\text{k}=\frac{2\text{a}\left(\pm\frac{\sqrt{3\left(\text{a}^2-1\right)}}{2}\right)}{\left(\pm\frac{\sqrt{3\left(\text{a}^2-1\right)}}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3+\text{a}^2}}{2}+\text{a}\right)^2}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3\left(\text{a}^2-1\right)}}{\sqrt{3+\text{a}^2}+2\text{a}}\tag5$$

Comment: The conclusion is that $a$ should be in $\mathbb{R}$ deprived of closed interval $[-1,1]$...

Comment: @jan eerland Why there is positive  sign between two square root of equation $(2)$

Comment: @mathophile sorry, my bad. The math is still correct by the way, I only swapped the minus for a plus. I corrected it now.

Comment: @JanEerland  Given answer is $a<-1$ or $a>1$